# Проблема с запуском CMD с параметрами (VBScript, Java)

Tags: java, cmd, vbscript

Мне нужно запустить командную строку (**cmd**) с некой командой, переданной в параметры. Делаю это с помощью скрипта **VBScript** (так как нужно будет в дальнейшем скрыть запуск окна...)
*Листинг скрипта:*

```
Dim WShell
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
WShell.Run objArgs(0), 1
Set WShell = Nothing
```

*Выполнение скрипта с передачей параметров* (запустить **cmd** и открыть браузер):

```
try {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript " + script.getAbsolutePath() + " \"cmd.exe \"start http://www.google.com\"\"");
} catch (IOException ex) {}
```

В результате выполнения открывается только лишь окно **cmd** без выполнения переданной в неё команды (открытия браузера). Какова может быть причина?
*Заранее спасибо)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
import java.io.IOException;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
            "wscript", "1.vbs", "cmd.exe /c start http://www.google.com"
        });
    }
}
```

PS: у меня сработало

Comment: Спасибо, дружище, заработало!)

Comment: @Dev0ps только мне кажется есть способ проще

Comment: Поведайте, если знаете)) Буду только признателен... Случайно не с помощью класса Desktop и его метода browse()?